# Unable to get Grep get information in Terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, grep, osx-mavericks, tcpdump

I'm unable to get 'get' in terminal using Grep.
This code used to work on Lion but in Maverick the GET doesn't show...

```
sudo tcpdump -i en1 -n -s 0 -w - | grep -a -o -E "Host\:\ .*|GET\ \/.*"
```

Any help or suggestions maybe?

Comment: First suggestion: explain what you want to do and give some sample input so we can "play" with it.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo tcpdump -i en1 -n -s 0 -w -`?

Comment: What i would like to have is a packet of all the websites i've visited including hosts, loaded images and text. (I'm doing research on using different webbrowsers and using tor so i can't really use the cache or history)

Until now it's just showing all the Hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo tcpdump -s 0 -A | egrep --color=never -a -o "Host\: .*|GET\ \/.*"`

The `-w -` writes the raw packets whereas the `-A` decodes to ASCII; handy for web pages (per man)

I found that if grep was outputting color, the Host: lines were output as empty lines.

Comment: Maybe then `unalias grep` and/or configure it to never show colors?

Comment: I added `--color=never` to this specific command, as normally I like the colour :)